# Subplots within a Tabbed figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

For the following script, the subplots/plots are going behind the tab, when executed. How can this be fixed?

```
h.mainfig = figure();
h.tabgroup = uitabgroup(h.mainfig, 'Position', [.05 .1 .9 .8]);

ntabs = 4;

for ii = 1:ntabs
    h.tab(ii) = uitab(h.tabgroup, 'Title', sprintf('Tab_%i', ii));
    for jj=1:2
        ax(jj)=subplot(2,1,jj);plot(1:10,sin(1:10));
    end
    linkaxes(ax,'x');
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a wrong call to `subplot`; it looks like Matlab creates too many axes and for some reason they are placed over the tabs.

A safe way to fix this is first create an axes right before entering the nested for-loop, then the subplots will be placed correctly.

Sample code:

```
clear
clc
close all

mainfig = figure();
tabgroup = uitabgroup(mainfig, 'Position', [.05 .1 .9 .8]);

for k = 1:4

    tab(k)=uitab(tabgroup,'Title', sprintf('Tab_%i', k));
    axes('parent',tab(k))
    for jj = 1:2

        subplot(2,1,jj);

        plot(1:10,(1:10).^k);
    end
end
```

Few screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

Yay!